# Install Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit without CD, DVD or USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multi-boot, windows-8.1, uefi

I am trying to get Ubuntu 13.10 onto my laptop, but do not have a CD, DVD or USB drive at hand. When I had this problem previously, I used [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), however when I tried doing that this time I bumped into [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unetbootin/+bug/1097981) bug.

The operating system currently on the laptop is Windows 8.1.

**My question is:**

How can I install Ubuntu 13.10 onto a separate partition of my hard drive, without the use of a CD/DVD or USB drive? I imagine that the partition could be formatted as ext4 through Windows somehow, the .iso extracted and the installer running from either the Windows partition or a separated smaller partition that would later be merged into the larger linux partition. Or something else entirely!

**Extra Info**

I did some research into the mbr bug and it turns out that it is because I am using UEFI. As I have Windows 8.1 installed, I cannot change this now.

Comment: Do you have a spare computer handy that you could install linux onto ?

Comment: @Lawrence sadly not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Easy BCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) can boot image files from your hard drive, I have done this on windows 7. It may work on windows 8.1 too.

Comment: I tried this and had a similar problem to with EasyBCD; AutoNeoGrub0 could not be loaded.

Comment: Marking this as a solution, since the AutoNewGrub0 problem was separate.